# Como pegar id dos dados criados em Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-database

Para exemplificar melhor... no meu banco de dados tenho uma coleção que armazena a seção dos usuários.

[image: Imagem da arvore de dados no firebase]

Após criar o usuário meu código JavaScript adiciona mais um usuário à coleção "users" e também um item em "session" que armazena o id do usuário.

Minha pergunta é: como pegar esse código que o firebase atribuí automaticamente aos itens de 'sesion'?

[image: Formulário de cadastro]

Segue o código javascript:

```
/* Pegar dados do usuario */
nome = document.querySelector('#username');
sobrenome = document.querySelector('#sobrenome');
createUserButton = document.querySelector('#submit');
email = document.querySelector('#email');
dataNascimento = document.querySelector('#data');
senha = document.querySelector('#senha');
confirm_senha = document.querySelector('#confirm-senha');
concordaTermos = document.querySelector('#check');

/*Cria evento do botão para enviar dados de login*/
createUserButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    /* Confere se o usuario concorda com os termos de uso */
    if (concordaTermos.checked) {

        /*cria o usuario*/
        firebase
            .auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, senha.value)
            .then(function() {
                /* Armazena dados no banco de dados */
                firebase.database()
                    .ref('users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                    .set({
                        'nome': nome.value,
                        'sobrenome': sobrenome.value,
                        'email': email.value,
                        'dataNascimento': dataNascimento.value

                    })
                    .then(function() {

                        /* Armazena seção do usuario */
                        firebase
                            .database()
                            .ref('sesion/')
                            .push()
                            .set(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);


                        console.log(secion);
                    })
            })

    }

})
```

Comment: Olá Kawan! Bem-vindo à nossa querida comunidade! Estive meio afastado daqui por uns tempos. Legal sua pergunta e não é difícil de solucionar (se você mesmo conseguir, poste depois uma resposta à sua própria pergunta! - é muito legal isso, sabia? Alguém pode ter uma dúvida parecida). Fiz uma edição só para consertar alguns termos. Como sugestão, use o termo correto para "session" para representar tempo na sua coleção. Outra sugestão, você precisa mesmo do Realtime database? Além disso, verifique se o Firestore não resolve seu problema. Conheça as diferenças lendo a documentação.

Comment: `Object.Keys(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)[0]` não resolveria o problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quando você cria usa o método push() em um referência do banco de dados ele retorna uma nova referência que possuo um campo .key
logo

```
const sessioRef = firebase.database().ref('sesion').push();
const codigo = sessionRef.key //use para o que quiser.
sessionRef.set(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
```